# How to change group text in Vuetify table-data(headers)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can i change group text in other language? [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHiV.png)

So, this is my v-data-table component. And I need customize language at places like in footer.page-text or group.header.

But idk how get access to "group"-text in headers to change on my language that i need
[Code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWea9.png)

Comment: Can you add some code ? hard to help without

Comment: Hi, please provide some minimal effort here. SO is not a how-to platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this particular text is currently non-localizable out of the box as it is hardcoded in the Vuetify source code - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTableHeaderDesktop.ts#L20

If it was translatable - you could have used Vue-i18n as exaplained in [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#vue-i18n).

However, you can work around this limitation by utilizing the `group.header` and `group.summary` slots. Just experiment with them.

Comment: where you able to customize this? I'm trying to change this too, but not only localize it but instead use an icon.

Comment: @code4jhon try this - https://codepen.io/seaskyways/pen/VwPbyER